# Blazor Asp.Net 6 Unhandled exceptions that are fatal to the APP (.exe)

Tags: blazor

Sadly [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0) does not explain that!

It basically only mentions exceptions that are fatal to the CIRCUIT.

So my assumption was, that basically every exception thrown in a method written in any .razor component AT WORST kills the circuit - NOT the C# application, the .exe.

This is however not true for

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthProvider

AuthProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += AuthProvider_AuthStateChanged;

AuthProvider_AuthStateChanged() {throw new Exception("kill the .exe entirely");};
```

So how on earth do I know which methods, in which places actually kill the app or simply reset the circuit.

That methods is an handler for an injected service, which is a scenario for errors not documented on the link above.

How can I implement GLOBAL exception handling for even such cases???